# Coalesce a field getting current time only in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

With regard to Sql Server 2005, how do I coalesce this statement with the current time if this select returns null -

```
select top 1 OrderDate as OldestOrderDate 
from ordersview 
ORDER BY OldestOrderDate
```

OrderDate is of type datettime.

Comment: Why do you have `top 1` without `ORDER BY`? Please don't tell me your view is `SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT ... ORDER BY ...`?

Comment: PS if your view does have `TOP 100 PERCENT ... ORDER BY ...` please remove it and read this (I just happened to blog about this very thing a few days ago): https://sqlblog.org/2012/02/28/why-people-think-some-sql-server-2000-behaviors-live-on-12-years-later

Comment: Don't worry, I'm aware that views are not ordered! Thank.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how you `coalesce this statement`:

```
coalesce(
  (select top 1 OrderDate as OldestOrderDate from ordersview),
  getDate());
```

If you only want the time portion:

```
coalesce(
  (select top 1 OrderDate as OldestOrderDate from ordersview),
  convert(varchar(10), getdate(), 8));
```

Here is an [example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1fa93/732)

> But what if I wanted to convert both OldestOrderDate and getdate to just the time potion, what should I do then? – Baz

In that case, try [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ac7c7/9).

Comment: But what if I wanted to convert both OldestOrderDate and getdate to just the time potion, what should I do then?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT OldestOrderDate = MAX(COALESCE(OrderDate, GETDATE()))
FROM (SELECT OrderDate = MAX(OrderDate) FROM dbo.ordersview UNION ALL SELECT NULL);
```

Comment: Ah, when I came across this question, I went along Mosty Mostacho's answer, but conversion to using MAX() – so obvious in hindsight! – is much superior. But honestly, I do not get all that complication. Why derived table? Why `UNION ALL`? `COALESCE(MAX(OrderDate), GETDATE())` should work just fine.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following:

```
select top 1 coalesce(OrderDate, getdate()) as OldestOrderDate from ordersview
```

This will return OrderDate if it is not null, else it will return the current date.

[Coalesce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) returns the first non-null value from its arguements.

Comment: if the table is empty you won't get anything